# How do i get ohlc data of only the latest candlestick of binance futures?

Tags: node.js, binance

I have tried many packages and also read the binance docs but not able to figure that how do I get only the latest candle OHLC data of a specific timeframe of binance futures.

I have been stuck at this problem from past week.
and I'm using NodeJs to code.